# Images from Hugo not displayed on GitHub pages

Tags: markdown, github-pages, hugo

I am trying to deploy a personal site built with Hugo to GitHub Pages. In that page, I want to put some images.
Here is the published page, with an image missing after the line `In the table of contents, it is the “parent” of the other articles inside the folder.` (you can see the alt text in there)
https://zq-psk.github.io/ssg/docs/hugo/articles/

The URL looks fine to me, I checked if all lower/uppercase is OK, including the extension.

It works locally, on localhost as well as when deployed as a static site.
Here is my GH repository:
https://github.com/ZQ-PSK/ssg
The "docs" folder is where GitHub pages takes the files from.
The "content" folder is the Markdown source.

This may have something to do with my Hugo config, I noticed that links to articles that I enter in MD also don't work.
I tried different combinations of "baseURL" and "relativeURLs" in Hugo config and it doesn't seem to help in any way.

Do you have any advice? Is there some way I can make absolute URLs that work locally as well as on GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's too late.
But you can fix this by adding canonifyURLs = true in your config.toml file.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give up and try a simpler approach.

Moved all my images to one folder at the top of the site's directory hierarchy, and now I use absolute URLs instead of relatives. It seems to do the job.

https://github.com/ZQ-PSK/ssg/commit/472b87c6c4cc591bca3e6c9c4ca4f7ff059e0912